# Read Less button scrolls back up

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, shopify

I have the below code, when I click read less I would like it to scroll up to the read more button.

When clicking the Read Less button, it shortens the description as expected but the page doesn't scroll back up to the top of the description div so I'm left looking at the page footer.

If anything could help with this, it'd be much appreciated. I believe I am overlooking a simple solutiom

Thanks

```js
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $( ".product-description-full" ).hide();
        
          $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('.readmore').click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var descriptionFull = document.querySelector('.product-description-full');
              $(descriptionFull).slideDown(500, 'swing');
              var descriptionShort = document.querySelector('.product-description-short');
              $(descriptionShort).slideUp(500, 'swing');
                    });
            $('.readless').click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var descriptionFull = document.querySelector('.product-description-full');
              $(descriptionFull).animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, '200');
              var descriptionShort = document.querySelector('.product-description-short');
              descriptionShort.style.display = 'block';
            });  
            });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
        the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
        five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged.
    </p>
    <div class="product-description-short lessmore">
        <a class="readmore" href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-description-full">
        <br />
        <p>
            It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
            sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
            desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
            versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
            text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from
            45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
        </p>
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it
        </p>

        <

        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled i
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled i
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled i
        </p>

        <div class="lessmore"></div>
        <span style="text-decoration: underline">
         <br />
         <a class="readless" href="#">Read Less</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

First way:

You assign an id to where you want to go back with the view, for example

```
<h1 id='title'>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

Then you change the href of the "Read Less" button to that id

```
<a class="readless" href="#title">Read Less</a>
```

You also need to comment out this line

```
$('.readless').click(function (event) {
//event.preventDefault();
```

Second way

You add an animation after you hide the text to go back to the top of the page

```
            $('.readless').click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var descriptionFull = document.querySelector('.product-description-full');
              $(descriptionFull).animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, '200');
              var descriptionShort = document.querySelector('.product-description-short');
              descriptionShort.style.display = 'block';
              $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); // this
              
            });
```